# Can't resolve symbol 'MainThread',Nullable'',and 'WorkerThread' in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem in **AsyncTask.java**
when imprort the the Library

`import android.support.annotation.MainThread;
 import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
 import android.support.annotation.WorkerThread;`

I receive the following error: `Can't resolve symbol`

I tried added the command

`dependencies {
...
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'}`

in **build.gralde(app)** but this does not work. Who can help me with this issue?

Comment: what is your minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion in build.gradle?

Comment: minSdkVersion 21 and  targetSdkVersion 26

Comment: rebuild your project once

Comment: yes, i try but failed...i think error version  annotation?

Comment: i think it due to mismatch version of sdk version  and annotation version . try using same version for both

Comment: same problem here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70327219/asynctask-errors-after-android-studio-update