# asynctask errors after android studio update

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

app have no error but asyntask.java has errors, abouth annotations, what can i do?

> import android.annotation.MainThread;
>
> import android.annotation.Nullable;
>
> import android.annotation.WorkerThread;
>
> import android.compat.annotation.UnsupportedAppUsage;
>
> Cannot resolve symbol 'MainThread'
>
> android.annotation.Nullable' is not public in 'android.annotation'.
> Cannot be accessed from outside package
>
> Cannot resolve symbol 'WorkerThread'
>
> Cannot resolve symbol 'annotation'

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.faysoft.shbmtal, PID: 8632
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done(AsyncTask.java:415)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: org.w3c.dom.DOMException: Only one root element allowed
        at org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.DocumentImpl.insertChildAt(DocumentImpl.java:420)
        at org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.InnerNodeImpl.appendChild(InnerNodeImpl.java:52)
        at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:307)
        at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:128)
```

Comment: `Cause by` line is pointing on some [parsing exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490231/android-xml-parsing-org-w3c-dom-domexception-only-one-root-element-allowed), your data source changed, not Android Studio. you have posted lines pointing on some import problems, thus project shouldn't built at all, but "code" section is an exception stacktrace from running app...

Answer (score 0):

`Cause by` line is pointing on some [parsing exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490231/android-xml-parsing-org-w3c-dom-domexception-only-one-root-element-allowed), your data source changed, not Android Studio